# Close program when browser closes

Tags: java, selenium, chromium, selenium-chromedriver, terminate

I'm creating a Chrome driver like so:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setBinary(CHROME);
chromeOptions.addArguments("user-data-dir=" + USER_DATA_DIR);

ChromeDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

If i close the browser (by clicking the red X) my java program just keeps alive. I then have  to click the terminate button in Eclipse. How can i exit it automaticly when the browser closes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Selenium` can't recognize manual operations on the browser. To terminate the program automatically close the browser using `driver.close();`

Comment: Oh, i see. It can't even detect navigation by the user. Is there any alternative?

Comment: @Guy will that close the application? or better, is close() more appropriate than quit() ?

Comment: @SimonMeusel the alternative is to put `driver.close();` or `driver.quit();` in the end of the script you are running.

Comment: @IoannisStefanou Yes, it will close the application. `close()` will close the currently focused window, `quit()` will close all the windows. When there is only one window there isn't any difference.